# r - ggplot2: filling the area between two rays

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot has two rays coming from the origin. I would like to shade the region going from ray 1 to ray 2 in a counter clockwise direction. I’m thinking that I might have to use geom_polygon. I would like to be able to do this for ***any two arbitrary rays***, but I can’t seem to figure it out.

*I’d like to stick to using cartesian coordinates.

Here’s an example of what I mean:

```
d <- data.frame()

base <- ggplot(d) + xlim(-5, 5) + ylim(-5, 5) + geom_blank()

ray1 <- geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=5,yend=4))
ray2 <- geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=0,yend=5))

shading <- geom_polygon(data=data.frame(x=c(0,5,5,0), y=c(0,4,5,5)), 
  aes(x,y), fill="blue", alpha=0.2)

base + ray1 + ray2 + shading
```

For this example, I was able to get the vertices of the polygon by inspection, but I'll be generating several random pairs of rays, and I don't want to go through this process manually each time.

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought it would be more simple; but i've arrived at this ugly solution. Here's a helper function which is meant to calculate all the intersection points along the limits defined in `base`

```
findslice<-function(seg1, seg2, base=NULL, lim=getlims(base)) {
    getlims<-function(x) {
        list(y=x$scales$get_scales("y")$limits,
        x=x$scales$get_scales("x")$limits)
    }
    gethit<-function(seg, lim) {
        with(seg$mapping, {
            x<-eval(x); y<-eval(y);
            xend<-eval(xend); yend<-eval(yend);
            dx<-(xend-x); dy<-(yend-y)
            bx<-ifelse(dx>0,max(lim$x), min(lim$x))
            by<-ifelse(dy>0,max(lim$y), min(lim$y))
            sx<-ifelse(dx>0,1, 3)
            sy<-ifelse(dy>0,2, 4)
            if(identical(dx,0)) {
                return(list(x=x,y=by, side=sy))
            }
            if (identical(dy,0)) {
                return(list(x=bx,y=y, side=sx))
            }
            nx<-bx
            ny<-(y+dy)*(nx-x)/dx
            side<-sx
            if (abs(ny)>abs(by)) {
                ny<-by
                nx<-(x+dx)*(ny-y)/dy
                side<-sy
            }
            return(list(x=nx, y=ny, side=side))
        })
    }
    p1<-gethit(seg1, lim)
    p2<-gethit(seg2, lim)
    side<-p1$side
    corners<-data.frame(x=lim$x[c(2,1,1,2)], y=lim$y[c(2,2,1,1)])
    r<-data.frame(x=c(seg1$mapping$x, p1$x), y=c(seg1$mapping$y, p1$y))
    while(side != p2$side) {
        r<-rbind(r, corners[side, ])
        side <- (side %% 4) +1
    }
    r<-rbind(r, data.frame(x=p2$x, y=p2$y))
    r
}
```

This will create the data.frame you need for your polygon plotting. For example

```
base <- ggplot(d) + xlim(-5, 5) + ylim(-5, 5) + geom_blank()

ray1 <- geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=5,yend=4))
ray2 <- geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=0,yend=5))

shading <- geom_polygon(data=findslice(ray1, ray2, base),
  aes(x,y), fill="blue", alpha=0.2)

base + ray1 + ray2 + shading + ggtitle("Take 1")
```

The idea is that it will go out the limits, and then start wrapping around the edges. So another example is

```
ray1 <- geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=5,yend=4))
ray2 <- geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=0,yend=5))

shading <- geom_polygon(data=findslice(ray1, ray2, base),
  aes(x,y), fill="blue", alpha=0.2)

base + ray1 + ray2 + shading + ggtitle("Take 2")
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

this is probably a bit buggy and clunky. I'd like to see some more elegant solutions from smarter people

I'm not clear how you want to handle the edges, though. see examples

```
shade_segs <- function(ray1, ray2, xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = xlim) {
  ray <- data.frame(x = c(ray1[1], pmin(ray1[3], xlim[2]),
                          pmin(ray1[3], ylim[2]), ray2[3]),
                    y = c(ray2[1], ray1[4],
                          ## how to handle the edges? :
                          pmin(ray2[4], xlim[2]), pmin(ray2[4], ylim[2])))
                          # pmin(ray1[4], xlim[2]), pmin(ray2[4], ylim[2])))
  # print(ray)
  require(ggplot2)

  ggplot() + xlim(xlim[1], xlim[2]) + ylim(ylim[1], ylim[2]) +
    geom_segment(aes_string(x = ray1[1], y = ray1[2],
                     xend = ray1[3], yend = ray1[4])) +
    geom_segment(aes_string(x = ray2[1], y = ray2[2],
                     xend = ray2[3], yend = ray2[4])) +
    geom_polygon(data = ray, aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) + 
    theme_bw()
}

library(gridExtra)
## c(x0, y0, x1, y1)
l <- list(shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, 5, 4), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, 0, 5)),
          shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, 2.5, 2.5), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, 1, 5)),
          shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, -1, 5), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, -.5, 5)),
          shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, -3, 5), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, -.5, -5)))
(do.call(arrangeGrob, c(l, list(nrow = 2, ncol = 2))))
```

[image]

or like this:

```
shade_segs <- function(ray1, ray2, xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = xlim) {
  ray <- data.frame(x = c(ray1[1], pmin(ray1[3], xlim[2]),
                          pmin(ray1[3], ylim[2]), ray2[3]),
                    y = c(ray2[1], ray1[4],
                          ## how to handle the edges? :
                          # pmin(ray2[4], xlim[2]), pmin(ray2[4], ylim[2])))
                          pmin(ray1[4], xlim[2]), pmin(ray2[4], ylim[2])))
  # print(ray)
  require(ggplot2)

  ggplot() + xlim(xlim[1], xlim[2]) + ylim(ylim[1], ylim[2]) +
    geom_segment(aes_string(x = ray1[1], y = ray1[2],
                     xend = ray1[3], yend = ray1[4])) +
    geom_segment(aes_string(x = ray2[1], y = ray2[2],
                     xend = ray2[3], yend = ray2[4])) +
    geom_polygon(data = ray, aes(x = x, y = y), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) + 
    theme_bw()
}

library(gridExtra)
## c(x0, y0, x1, y1)
l <- list(shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, 5, 4), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, 0, 5)),
          shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, 2.5, 2.5), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, 1, 5)),
          shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, -1, 5), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, -.5, 5)),
          shade_segs(ray1 = c(0, 0, -3, 5), 
                     ray2 = c(0, 0, -.5, -5)))
(do.call(arrangeGrob, c(l, list(nrow = 2, ncol = 2))))
```

[image]

the second one makes more sense to me.

Comment: Hehe, and you thought yours was clunky. I wish ggplot didn't just abandon plotting the polygon if it any part of it goes outside the plot limits.

Comment: like you, I thought it was simple at first, then an hour later.... And you could swap the `*lim` with `coord_cartesian()` to avoid that, if I understand correctly

Comment: Thanks! The examples you gave are very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

So here are two more ways to do this. The first uses a brute force approach, which is slow but by far the simplest. The second uses the feature-set in packages `sp` and `rgeos` for manipulating map geometries. This is conceptually similar to the solution using convex hulls.

**First approach:**

```
r1 <- data.frame(x=c(0,5),y=c(0,4))
r2 <- data.frame(x=c(0,0),y=c(0,5))

th1  <- with(r1,atan2(y[2],x[2]))
th2  <- with(r2,atan2(y[2],x[2]))

is.between <- function(x,lo,hi) {
  if (lo<=hi) return(x>=lo & x<=hi)
  return(!(x<lo & x>hi))
}

df    <- expand.grid(x=seq(-5,5,len=200),y=seq(-5,5,len=200))
df$th <- atan2(df$y,df$x)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping=aes(x,y))+
  xlim(-5,5) + ylim(-5,5)+
  geom_tile(data=df[is.between(df$th,th1,th2),],fill="blue",alpha=.2)+
  geom_line(data=r1)+
  geom_line(data=r2)
```

[image]

This approach recognizes that, since your rays start at the origin, we can create a grid of tiles covering the whole space and then just color the ones that make an angle with the x-axis between the angles swept out by your two rays. The code below shades the areas "between" `r1` and `r2`, in counter-clockwise fashion. So if `r2` comes first, it will shade the external angle (try swapping the definitions of `r1` and `r2`). Note that we are using `geom_tile(...)` to do the shading.

Using your formalism:

```
base <- ggplot() + xlim(-5,5) + ylim(-5,5) + geom_blank()
ray1 <- geom_line(data=r1, aes(x,y))
ray2 <- geom_line(data=r2, aes(x,y))
shading <- geom_tile(data=df[is.between(df$th,th1,th2),],aes(x,y),
                     fill="blue",alpha=.2)
base + ray1 + ray2 + shading
```

**Second approach:**

```
library(sp)      # for SpatialPolygons(...), etc.
library(rgeos)   # for gIntersection(...)
th1  <- with(r1,atan2(y[2],x[2]))
th1  <- ifelse(th1>0, th1, 2*pi+th1)
th2  <- with(r2,atan2(y[2],x[2]))
th2  <- ifelse(th2>0, th2, 2*pi+th2)

th    <- if(th1<th2){seq(th1,th2,length=100)} else {c(seq(th1,2*pi,length=100),seq(0,th2,length=100))}
df    <- data.frame(x=c(0,5*sqrt(2)*cos(th),0),y=c(0,5*sqrt(2)*sin(th),0))
slice <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(df)),"1")))
box   <- readWKT("POLYGON((-5 -5,-5 5,5 5,5 -5,-5 -5))")
shade <- gIntersection(box,slice)
sh.df <- as.data.frame(shade@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords)

base <- ggplot() + xlim(-5,5) + ylim(-5,5) + geom_blank()
ray1 <- geom_line(data=r1, aes(x,y))
ray2 <- geom_line(data=r2, aes(x,y))
shading <- geom_polygon(data=sh.df,aes(x,y),fill="blue",alpha=.2)
base + ray1 + ray2 + shading
```

[image]

This approach takes advantage of the feature-set in `rgeos`, specifically the ability to calculate the intersection of SpatialPolygons. It creates two SpatialPolygons: one called `box` that simply covers the area from (-5,-5) to (5,5), and another called `slice` that is the pie-slice between your two rays. We have to use a radius for the pie that is `5*sqrt(2)` to guarantee that the slice extends at least to the corners of `box`. Then we calculate the intersection fo these two polygons using `gIntersection(...)` in the `rgeos` package, and use ggplot to plot it *as a polygon*.

While the syntax for creating the polygons is tortuous, this method is much faster.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to sp and rgeos!

Answer (score 4):

A partial solution in the case that the rays always happen to form an angle of *less than* 180 degrees is to take the points that form the convex hull of the polygon and plot that.

```
rayX <- c(0,5,0,0)
rayY <- c(0,4,0,5)
rays <- data.frame(cbind(rayX,rayY))
Mypoly <- rays[chull(rays),]

shading2 <- geom_polygon(data=Mypoly, aes(rayX,rayY), fill="blue", alpha=0.2)

base + ray1 + ray2 + shading2
```

[image]

If you want the area to extend outside of the plot region it is simple since you specified that the rays are from the origin. Simply multiply the convex hull by a constant larger than the range of the plot limits (and then use `coord_cartesian` so the polygon is not thrown away from the plot).

```
MypolyExt <- Mypoly * 10

base2 <- ggplot(d) + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(-5, 5),ylim=c(-5, 5)) +geom_blank()
shading3 <- geom_polygon(data=MypolyExt, aes(rayX,rayY), fill="blue", alpha=0.2)
base2 + ray1 + ray2 + shading3
```

[image]

To make this work with the case in which the angles are 180 degrees or greater (e.g. Take 2 in MrFlick's answer) would take slightly more work. One way is to assign a set of points that form a square in the outer limit of the plot. Then if the angle of the ray is greater than 180 degrees keep those points and then grab the convex hull.

Comment: Thanks! I like your idea about using MypolyExt.